# Dropdownlist ID change name

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

The headline is not good. I don't know how anything better to write in the headline. But here it comes.

I am making a soccerfield with all the different positions. On each position I have a dropdownlist that shows the players in the team.

I made parts of the dropdownlists and came to realised that I was doing it wrong.

```
try
{
     int pos = list[i].positionsID;

     if (pos == 1)
     {
          ddlGoal.Visible = true;
          lblGoal.Visible = true;

          ddlGoal.DataSource = list1;
          ddlGoal.DataValueField = "id";
          ddlGoal.DataTextField = "name";
          ddlGoal.DataBind();
      }
 }  catch ...
```

It should only show the position of there are any players on that position. It all works fine... but i have 28 positions, and there for 28 of the above try/catch things.

I want to scale it down, by only making one.

If i let all the dropdownlists have the same name as the postions saved on my database I should be able to make just one. So i have tried that:

```
try
{
    int pos = list[i].positionsID;

     if (pos != 0)
     {
           string ddl = "ddl" + list3[i].positionsNavn.ToString();
           ddl.Visible = true;
           lblGoal.Visible = true;    
           ddlGoal.DataSource = list1;
           ddlGoal.DataValueField = "id";
           ddlGoal.DataTextField = "name";
           ddlGoal.DataBind();
      }
 }  catch...
```

It doesn't work. How do i get hold of the dropdownlist with ID ddlGoalKeeper when i am creating the ID as:

```
string ddl = "ddl" + list3[i].positionsNavn.ToString();
```

Any ideas or help??

Comment: Can you post your html code on where you are creating the dropdownlist and also where you want to read the dropdownlist as shown above

Comment: here it is:<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlGoalKeeper" runat="server">
                </asp:DropDownList>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you need. Given the ID of any control you can use

```
FindControl
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.findcontrol.aspx

to get any control in the control tree. You wil need to use it on the naming container that contains the control i.e.

```
Panel.FindControl(controlID)
```

or use the recursive version wriiten by a certain Jeff Atwood

http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/06/recursive-pagefindcontrol.html

Alternatively - construct a Dictionary collection will all your dropdowns mapped to IDs and get them for this. Could be more efficient with more setup